# Sending POST request with CURL and proxies

Tags: php, curl, proxies

I've been trying to fix this all day but I haven't been able to figure out the solution. I am trying to post a request to a website through my website on a php file. I am using curl and would like to use proxies, however I am not getting any response. I am with namecheap and even had them look into it and they can't seem to figure it out either. I got them to open port 8080 and no success.

```
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $port );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 0 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURL_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $response;
```

This is my code which will not give me a response.
When I sending this without any proxies it goes through and I get a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the error code code and message from a failed function call is a good idea as it might give you a clue about what's going on.

The PHP documentation for `CURLOPT_PROXTYPE` doesn't include `'HTTP'` as a valid type. It does list `CURLPROXY_HTTP` though.

Comment: Unfortunately this also does not return a response from the server I am trying to reach. If there is more information you may need please let me know and I can post it.

Comment: **Get the error code** from curl, and **the error message**

Comment: I guess my first mistake was to not add in a check for curl errors. I changed, what you mentioned in your answer and checked the error code and it was giving me a bad proxy which I changed and it is working now. Thank you!